# i need help in simple html/php code

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

i want to add two text boxes and a Submit button to a HTML form and Invite the user to enter a first name and surname. When the button is clicked, i want to display the first name and surname in the textboxes using php code.

note: html and php are in the same file named exercise1.php.

Comment: There are lot of tutorials available. Firstly try to do something.

Comment: Why did you remove the code you attempted?

Answer (score 2):

Pending some input validation and checking...

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    echo 'Your name is: ' . $_POST['fname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lname'];
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <label for="fname">First name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" />

    <label for="lname">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

index.html following codes :

```
<html>
<form action="recive.php" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="firstname" >
<input type="submit" value="send !" >
</form>
</html>
```

recive.php in the same directory write following codes :

```
<?php

echo $_POST['firstname'];

?>
```

this is the simplest one for better you can use ajax

Comment: farhad bhai could u plz check my question again. i have made some changes to it. thanks.